# jQuery mobile form losing styling

Tags: jquery, forms, mobile, jquery-mobile

I'm using the following code in order to put mobile styling on an input form:

```
items.push('<form id="flatmetrics"><table >');
for (i = 0; i < len; i += 1) {
    row = resultflat.rows.item(i);
    if (row.currentmetric == 0) {
        items.push('<tr><td width="20%"><label for="' + row.flatno + '">' + row.flatdescription + '</td><td width="20%">' + row.previousmetric +'</label></td><td width="60%"><input type="number" name="' + row.flatno + '" id="' + row.flatno + '" flat="' + row.flatdescription + '" building="' + row.buildingcode + '" class="field" value="' + row.previousmetric + '"/></td></tr>');
    } 
    else {
        items.push('<tr><td width="20%"><label for="' + row.flatno + '">' + row.flatdescription + '</td><td width="20%">' + row.previousmetric +'</label></td><td width="60%"><input type="number" name="' + row.flatno + '" id="' + row.flatno + '" flat="' + row.flatdescription + '" building="' + row.buildingcode + '" class="field" value="' + row.currentmetric + '"/></td></tr>');
    }
}
items.push('</table></form>');

$('#entriesflatFM').show();
$('#entriesflatFM').html(items.join('\n')).page();
```

After the first visit the form does not have the enhanced style.

Does anyone know why this is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried `.trigger('create')`?

```
$('#entriesflatFM').html(items.join('\n')).trigger('create');
```

Or perhaps select the new `<form>` element before using `.trigger('create')`:

```
$('#entriesflatFM').html(items.join('\n')).children().trigger('create');
```

Also you are using the same selector twice in a row, you should chain your function calls when possible:

```
$('#entriesflatFM').show();
$('#entriesflatFM').html(items.join('\n')).page();
```

can be:

```
$('#entriesflatFM').show().html(items.join('\n')).page();
```

## Update

If none of this works then you could try calling the specific widget functions for each type of widget:

```
$('#entriesflatFM').show().html(items.join('\n'))
    .find('[data-type="range"]').slider().end()
    .find('select').selectmenu();
```

Comment: nothing of the above works for me. The strange thing is that if i choose to go back ang forward to another choice of previous menu also the enhanced style gone away...